# Custom ImageView class is overlapping other elements in screen

Tags: android, imageview, overlap

I am building an app that accesses a WordPress website API to list the posts, which has a preview like this:

[image]

The big white space at the top is the image of the post, which I implemented by copying a code I found online, creating a class that extends `ImageView` and modifying somethings, making the image 100% wide, because previously I couldn't achieve it.

It works, but the image is overlapping the other elements:

[image]

This is the code I've copied and adapted:

```
public class ProportionalImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

  public ProportionalImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable d = getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
      int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
      int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
      setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

    else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to make the image 100% wide but keep the proportion and not overlap, of course.

My layout file, for each square:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="280dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="32sp"
  android:background="@android:color/white">

  <skillpoint.com.skillpoint.ProportionalImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgImageUrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgImageUrl"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    style="@style/Post.Preview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgImageUrl"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextColorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    style="@style/Post.Preview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:text="00/00/0000"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextColorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    style="@style/Post.Preview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextColorSecondaryDark"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your **`style="@style/Post.Preview"`** with question

Comment: I think you may want to use a `LinearLayout` with `android:weightSum` and then your other views inside it.

Comment: In your "ProportionalImageView" you are calculating height, Please take a look into onMesure() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Custom `ImageView` class is overlapping other elements in screen

Because your `RelativeLayout` has static height   just change it to  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` you issue will be solved check the below images

Use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="280dp"
```

Try this Remove static height from your `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <com.example.user33.workingtestapp.ProportionalImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgImageUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/disha" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgImageUrl"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgImageUrl"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
        android:textColor="#ff00"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="00/00/0000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

**without static hight**

[image]

**with static hight**

[image]

Comment: It worked, but the image still makes the block bigger.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 make your imageview hight smaller      `android:layout_height="100dp"`